# Сравнить две версии документа (.pdf .docx .xlsx) и найти отличия, используя бесплатные библиотеки C#

Tags: c#, парсер, pdf

Стоит задача выявить изменения в двух версиях документа, насколько я понимаю, я не смогу найти подобный функционал в готовом виде. Эту задачу нужно будет выполнить, используя парсер документа (.pdf .docx  .xlsx). Прошу подскажите, какие есть бесплатные библиотеки для подобных задач, могу ли я найти подробную документацию на эти библиотеки? Может есть более простой и удобный способ получить информацию с этих форматов в удобном для обработке виде? Мои знания малы, но для такой задачи я надеюсь их хватит. Спасибо.

Comment: Для отображения разницы в документах doc/docx и xls/xlsx у Tortoise есть набор diff-скриптов https://github.com/TortoiseGit/tortoisesvn/tree/master/contrib/diff-scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если документ был изменен, достаточно проверки хэшей файлов (алгоритм выбрать наименее подверженный коллизиям), - это наиболее вероятный признак изменения файла. Для визуализации изменений в `.docx` или `.xslx` достаточно открыть эти файлы как `.zip` архив и сравнить содержащиеся в них `.xml` файлы; относительно `.pdf` - разбирать их также несложно, если быть знакомым со спецификацией данного формата, а вот чтобы не изобретать велосипед - проще поискать подходящую библиотеку в галерее [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=pdf).